# How was the Stack Exchange community born?

Tags: discussion

It is clear that, for Stack Exchange to work, it is necessary for there to be a big community of people like it has now. In general this is necessary for a lot of other websites like Wikipedia.

But there was a moment when they didn't have a big enough community that made it work so well.

My questions are:

How did the Stack Exchange community reach the critical mass necessary to work well?

What is the best way, in general, to create a site that needs a big community working on it and what steps should follow the small community to make it thrive?

Assume the site is interesting enough so a lot of people in the world would be willing to join to the community but the site is not known (like happened with Stack Exchange when it was small).

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [How was Stack Overflow launched?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3964/186560) (Both seem to ask how the site founders gathered a sufficiently large group of users, and what about their model can be copied by others.)